# Evenly distribute some points in different polygons (blocks)

Tags: polygon, point, snapping

I need to evenly distribute some points in different polygons (blocks) that I have within a study area in QGIS. Does anyone know any tool or way to do it?
[image]

Comment: Yout question is very broad. Could you provide more information, e.g. are the points supposed to be distributed randomly or following a fixed raster. Could you perhaps present some sample of your data?

Comment: I did this for forest stands awhile ago—it should apply to your case: https://github.com/redfoxgis/generate_plots